# How to make associatedtype be a protocol?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm struggling to implement this protocol using another protocol as its associatedtype.

I have these two:

```
public protocol CarToken: Any {
}

public protocol Car: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Token: CarToken

    func doThis(_ token: Token)
    func doThat(_ token: Token)
}
```

If I try to implement the Car like this, **it works**:

```
class ObjectThatImplementsCarToken: CarToken {
}

extension FooBar: Car {
    func doThis(_ token: ObjectThatImplementsCarToken) { ... }
    func doThat(_ token: ObjectThatImplementsCarToken) { ... }
}
```

But if instead I use a protocol *ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken*, the compiler **won't accept**:

```
protocol ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken: CarToken {
}

// Error:
extension FooBar: Car {
    func doThis(_ token: ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken) { ... }
    func doThat(_ token: ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken) { ... }
}
```

The compiler thinks FooBar doesn't conform to Car.

Why is that? I want those functions to accept multiple types that implements ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken, which by extension they all implement CarToken. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, the functions doThis and doThat can only make use of properties and functions that are defined in CarToken anyway so what's the point?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Inside my doThis function I don't want to need to cast my type from CarToken to ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken just to access some property that only exists in ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken. I mean, if ProtocolThatExtendsCarToken extends CarToken, I don't know why the compiler won't accept it as an associatedype

Comment: Well see the linked question above as to why the compile won't let you do this and then you might need to rethink your design .